# Django rest framework query? Every todo item jas a teamowner. I want to have a query with all todos per Team. So

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class Teams(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='team_icons', null='True', blank='True')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='member')

class ToDo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', related_name='todos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads', null='True', blank='True')
    teamOwner = models.ForeignKey("Teams", related_name='team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

==> the serializers

```
class ToDoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields= (
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'owner',
            'file',
            'teamOwner',
        )

        model = ToDo

class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = (

            'id',
            'name',
            'file',

        )
        model = Teams
```

And finally the view code of the query:

```
class ListTodo(generics.ListCreateAPIView):


    queryset = models.ToDo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ToDoSerializer

 
    def get_queryset(self):

        owner_queryset = self.queryset.filter(Teams)
        return owner_queryset
```

Every combination in .filter(xxx) fails. ik want as outcome the Team ID or PK number in the return queryset.
Iam a beginner so i hope i explained my problem in a clear way

Answer (score 0):

you can write like ;

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    # if you want to logged user teams' todo list
    owner_queryset = self.queryset.filter(Teams=self.request.user)

    return owner_queryset
```

Best regards,